# Graph API vs iOS SDK in Facebook App

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

What is actually the advantage/disadvantage of each method? I've used the graph API before and it seems that it can do anything I want in Facebook.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You seem to confuse SDK and API. API is an interface to a service that programmers can use. SDK is a library that uses this API. Facebook iOS SDK is a new version of the Facebook SDK that uses the Graph API and also allows you to call the older REST API.

```
 You
----------------------
 Various SDKs
----------------------
 REST API | Graph API
----------------------
 Facebook internals
```

An SDK does not have to implement all of an API. And the Graph API in this case does not support all the things that the older REST API supported, like [video upload](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=10214). Hope that helps a bit.

Comment: ok, i've been calling graph API from my app without facebook SDK, is that seem to be a bad practice? Do you think that the best way is to use the official sdk?

Comment: No, it's perfectly OK to use the API directly. I guess that most people would go for the official SDK though, since that means writing and maintaining less code yourself.